# Proxy setting using chrome extension not working with chrome43

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am using chrome extension for switching the chrome proxy setting at runtime.
I have tested my code on chrome 59 and chrome 69 which is working fine.
However, the same code is failing when being tried upon chrome43.
The proxy is not getting switched and the requests are getting directly routed.

Do we have extension issues with chrome43?
Is there any other way to switch the chrome proxy at runtime without the need to restart the chrome browser?

```
let proxy = xx.xx.xx.xx; //intentionally masked for sharing code
let configPAC = {
       mode: "pac_script",
       pacScript: {
        data : "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {  return 'PROXY "+proxy+"';}",
        mandatory:true  
     }
    };
                        
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: configPAC, scope: "regular"}, function() { console.log("Setting custom proxy here!");});
```

Comment: The API was fixed/changed several times over the years so it's only natural that an ancient prehistoric version of Chrome works differently,

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. 
But is there some way we can use this feature for chrome43? These features were introduced since version 35 and should be available for version43.